# Problems with connecting to PHP through Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to send a JSON object from my android application to my site's database. However, I seem to not get any type of connection and I don't get any exception errors. I am currently trying to get a connection just with java in eclipse but still no luck.

submitAlbum.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["albumId"])){
    $albumId = json_decode($_POST["albumId"]);
}
```

The java Code:

```
String albumId = "qjlix";

    try{
        //Creates JSON object
        JSONObject tempObj = new JSONObject();
        tempObj.put("albumId", albumId);

        //Creates connection to URL
        URL targetUrl = new URL("http://example.com/submitAlbum.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(500);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content_Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(tempObj.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());;
    }
```

Is their something I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What response do you get on your android side. Did you mean Content-Type and not Content_Type

Comment: @RobertI I don't get any response, even when i prosperously make the url incorrect. And yeah I was experimenting with the request property.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a POST parameter/key 'albumId' of which the value is a json text. Instead you send a json text containing a json parameter 'albumId'.

Php script and client code do not match.

First decide if you want to POST key=value pairs. Or want to POST json text. Then handle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that they were not matching. However, that is not the only issue preventing the PHP from running. When I configure the PHP to write something to my database just by connecting to it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the PHP would not even run until run this on the client side:

```
conn.getResponseCode();
```

So in the end I just made the PHP code already have a albumId set, it just needed something to connect to it. Then it would submit it to my database.

PHP:

```
 $albumId = "qjlix";
```

Then in my java all I needed to do was get a connection the the PHP file.

Java:

```
 try{
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/submitAlbum.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("albumId = this");
        writer.close();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("worked");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Did not work");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("exception thrown");
    }
```

I was testing the Java in IntelliJ even through it's going to be used in an Android application. I plan on just using Volley since HttpURLConnection is weird sometimes. Thanks!!!